# Cout in function prints too many times in C++

Tags: c++, cin

I am trying to make a basic game using C++ just to expand my understanding of the language. I have the following code and when the user inputs an invalid answer they will get asked to try again.

```
void turn_update()
{
    player = (player % 2 == 0)? 1 : 2;
    mark = (player == 1)? 'X' : 'O';

    cout << " Please make your move, " << mark << ":" << endl;
    int x = 0;
    while(!(cin >> x) || x > 9 || x < 1 || board[x] == 'X' || board[x] == 'O')
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << " Invalid input. Try again: ";
    }
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    board[x] = mark;
    draw_board(board);
}
```

When the user inputs say "123456" the response would be:

```
 Please make your move, X:
 123456
 Invalid input. Try again:
```

Now that is what I want and same goes for a single letter. E.g:

```
 Please make your move, X:
 a
 Invalid input. Try again:
```

But when the user inputs two or more letters the `Invalid input: Try again:` will print out the same number of times as the number of letters entered...

```
 Please make your move, X:
 aa
 Invalid input. Try again:  Invalid input. Try again:

 Please make your move, X:
 aaa
 Invalid input. Try again:  Invalid input. Try again:  Invalid input. Try again:
```

Can someone please explain why? I don't have a lot of experience with C++ and if there are any tips you have for the general code I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: `std::getline` may be useful. And `std::cin.ignore()` only ignore 1 character according to [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) and [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: cout << "\n" << endl;  why two version

Comment: @user202729 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use only cin.clear() in while loop.

```
while (!(cin >> x) || x > 9 || x < 1 || board[x] == 'X' || board[x] == 'O'))
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << " Invalid input. Try again: ";
}
```

Comment: I tried that but then it prints out ` "Invalid input. Try again: "` a million times

Comment: I am using visual studio and everything runs ok

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << " Please make your move, " << mark << ":" << endl;
int x = 0;

while (true)
    while (!(cin >> x)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Please provide a valid number in range 1 - 9. Try again: ";
    }
    if (x < 1 || x > 9) {
        cout << "value out of range 1 - 9"
        continue;
    }
    if (board[x] != 'X' && board[x] != 'O') {
        break;
    }
    cout << "Cant make a move at " << x << " occupied by: " << board[x];
}
```

Comment: You don’t need the `break` or the `continue` if you reorganize the logic a bit. `if (x < 1 || x > 9) std::cout << “bad value\n”; else if (board[x] == ‘X’ || board[x] == ‘Y’) std::cout << “can’t move there\n”;`.